# If there is a $2\times 2$ matrix $A^2 = I$, what will the complete solution set for $A$ be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, involutions

[image: the steps i did]So the basic thing I started with was equating the diagonal and the other other two entries of matrix $A$ respectively which gives, $$a=\pm d, \\b=c$$ But there is this matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\ \frac12 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ who's square also equals $I$.

So, what error did I make? And what will the method to obtain the complete solution set be?

Comment: Please write how did you obtain the wrong conditions. Oterwise it is impossible to say what error did you make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trace of a matrix $A$ with $A^2=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091929/trace-of-a-matrix-a-with-a2-i)

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1091947/977780) answer.

Comment: Did you compute $A^2$ in general and set it equal to $I$? It looks like you just guessed (incorrectly) at *some* solutions, without attempting to find *all* solutions. So your fundamental error was thinking that guessing solutions was sufficient.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. It's hard to pin point your the error in your calculations if you don't show your calculations.

Comment: I've added just now. the calculation part i did. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Be *very* careful. If $ax=ay$, is it valid to conclude $x=y$?

Comment: I think yes? The common part could be cancelled out

Comment: By that reasoning, since $0 \cdot 3 = 0 \cdot 4$ we conclude that $3=4$?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you got the condition on the entries of the matrix. There are infinitely many such matrices. To see this note that $A^2=I$ implies that the minimal polynomial of the matrix is $(x-1), (x+1)$ or $(x+1)(x-1)$ since the minimal polynomial divides the annihilating polynomial $x^2-1$. This means that A is diagonalisable and hence has the form
$$
A=I,\quad A=-I,\quad A=S\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}S^{-1}
$$
for any invertible matrix $S$. All these choices satisfy
$A^2=I$.

Comment: $A=I$ is also possible, of course.

Comment: $A=-I$ works too . The condition on the characteristic polynomial does not stay that $A$ should have exactly one eigenvalue $1$ and one eigenvalue  $-1$. It can have two eigenvalues $1 $(and thus $I=A$) or two eigenvalues $-1$ (and thus $A=-I$)

Comment: I've just added the calculations i did. Sorry